# What does "★20% damage" mean in Dead Cells?

Tags: dead-cells

In a game of *Dead Cells* (with the new update), I just received this item (emphasis mine, sorry but I can't get a screenshot of any quality here easily):

> Electric Whip V
> 442 DPS 
> +50% damage
>
> Automatically targets nearby enemies. Ignores shields.
>
> ## ★20% damage
>
> ◆+30% damage to a burning target

**What does "★20% damage" mean? Is it a typo that is supposed to say "+20% damage"? Is it a mis-starred downside that makes my attacks only deal 20% damage?**

I am playing on Nintendo Switch.

[image: A bad screenshot.]

Comment: @Wrigglenite shouldn't it have that tag to specify this is a Switch-specific problem?

Comment: @Wrigglenite no, [according to Eurogamer](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2019-02-15-dead-cells-massive-pimp-my-run-update-out-now-on-consoles), the update is now on all consoles, has been on PC for a while

Comment: @Wrigglenite I don't know, I only play on Switch. The modifier glitch/typo (if it is one) might only be there

Comment: So the platform tag shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 5):

Star identifies "rare" modifier. Usually can be found on Legendary items, but sometimes may appear on usual items.

I doubt star is used instead of "+", most likely "+" is just missing.

[Source #1](https://www.reddit.com/r/deadcells/comments/8ho4lb/help_me_understand_the_stats_on_gear/), [Source #2](https://steamcommunity.com/app/588650/discussions/0/1694923613867820572/)

Comment: So you mean to say that it's a rare weapon modifier which adds 20% dmg to the weapon?

Comment: @Neon1024 That’s correct: this weapon deals 120% of its normal damage.